# Adding cells recursively in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet

I have my data and I want to add it in this way (suppose that B_i is i-th B cell): C1=SUM(B1:B1), C2=SUM(B1:B2), C_i(or Ci)=SUM(B1:Bi). How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C1 put:

```
=SUM($B$1:$B1)
```

And drag down.

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 10,000 rep! I have learned a lot by reading some of your answers.